# Should i pass a Backgroundworker to method

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have an app that has several methods that take a long time to complete.  I am using a backgroundworker to run these methods and keep my UI responsive.  My methods look something like

```
public void DoSomething()
{
   while( HaveMoreWork )
   {
     // do work
   }
}
```

Now i want the UI to be able to cancel this at any time so I have changed my methods to take a Backgroundworker like so

```
public void DoSomething(Backgroundworker worker)
{

   while( HaveMoreWork && !worker.CancelationPending )
   {
     // do work
   }
}
```

My question is, is there a better way to do this.  Seems like passing a Backgroundwoker as an argument to all these methods is a bit messy.  What is best practice for this?

Comment: They must know the worker, either as a parameter or a global var. This looks good.

Answer (score 1):

I am using global variable

```
private BackgroundWorker _bwSearch = new BackgroundWorker();

private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
{
     _bwSearch = new BackgroundWorker();
     _bwSearch.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
     _bwSearch.DoWork += bwSearch_DoWork;
     _bwSearch.RunWorkerCompleted += bwSearch_RunWorkerCompleted;
}
```

when clicked on stop button

```
 private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      _bwSearch.Abort();
 }
```

---

**Updated:**
Also I am using this simple helper class that is inherited from BackgroundWorker

```
public class AbortableBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorker
    {
        private Thread _workerThread;

        protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            _workerThread = Thread.CurrentThread;

            try
            {
                base.OnDoWork(e);
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;

                Thread.ResetAbort();
            }
        }

        public void Abort()
        {
            if (_workerThread != null)
            {
                _workerThread.Abort();

                _workerThread = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: BackgroundWorker uses the thread pool, which means you should never call abort on a BackgroundWorker. I believe a better approach would be to change your btnCancel_Click to:
if(_bwSearch.IsBusy) _bwSearch.CancelAsync();

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DoSomethingService
{
    private volatile bool _stopped = false;

    public void Start(object socketQueueObject)
    {
        while (!_stopped)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _stopped = true;
    }
}

...

var doSomethingService = DoSomethingService();
doSomethingService.Start();
...
doSomethingService.Stop();
```